# Keep a counter for every served row in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this **file.php** file that is doing a

```
SELECT 'NAME' FROM users WHERE CONDITION
```

I would like to keep track of the rows that have been served for every call.
so I'd like to keep a counter for each row.

What is the most efficient way in **PHP** to update a counter for every row that was fetched?

Comment: Nice question. What is your exact use case?

Comment: This is pretty much it. I need to know how many times rows were served to my users.

Comment: EDIT: Misunderstood the question.

Comment: What do you mean @PenguinCoder?

Comment: Misunderstood the question. Thought you wanted to return a count of all rows in one call to the user, not keep track of how many times a particular row was looked up.

Comment: Is storing the ID's of the served rows possible?

Comment: Best bet is to use apache log, or PHP to do the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add an extra column  for view/fetch count

```
SELECT          
    ...., views+1 as view
FROM table_name
WHERE ....

UPDATE table_name
SET views = views + 1
WHERE ...;
```

you can put it in a `Transaction`

Answer (score -1):

You could always add a `fetched_at` column to that table, then update that if/when you fetch records:

```
UPDATE users SET fetched_at=UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE ...condition...
```

Then fetch as you would normally. You would apply an identical condition to both cases. Keep in mind that if you're using `JOIN` this might be much more difficult to implement.

If you need to keep a count, use an `INT` column:

```
UPDATE users SET fetched_count=fetched_count+1 WHERE ...condition...
```

Comment: Is storing the ID's of the served rows possible? So that I can UPDATE by that list

Comment: MySQL won't store them for you. Obviously these can be extracted from your result-set and reinjected in the form of an `UPDATE` though.